# Biopython's Esearch for Pubmed gives different result for a given time frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, biopython, pubmed

I am trying to use biopython's [Entrez](https://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Entrez-module.html) package to get the list of papers published on `Pubmed` between a given time frame (let's say I want to get all papers published between 2019/09/19 and 2019/09/20) using the search term `"cancer"`.

I am using the following code to do this -

```py
from Bio import Entrez
from datetime import date

Entrez.email = "myemail@mydomain.com"

handle = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term="cancer", retmode="xml", mindate = '2019/09/19',  maxdate = '2019/09/20', datetype="pdat")

records = Entrez.read(handle)

count = int(records["Count"])   

print(count)
```

Output -

```
142
```

The above code indicates that there are 142 papers that were published between 2019/09/19 and 2019/09/20 on Pubmed and mentioned the word cancer.

However, when I search the Pubmed website using the same filters for dates the same term. It gives me only 28 result. Here is the output on the website of my search query -

[image]

Can anyone explain to me why is there a difference in the count of papers from the biopython library and what I see on the pubmed website? Is there anything I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Strange! I get 142 search results: https://imgur.com/oBlDKJj. Maybe a timing issue? Try clearing all filters and re-run search.

Comment: I also got 142 search results. It's possible that the two search methods don't updated data at the same time. This could cause inconsistent results when searching for very recent publications.

Comment: Thanks for testing it out at your end. It may be an issue of timing for both the methods. BTW, I checked a few cases from those 142 cases as well, and it seems that the result is incorrect. For instance one of the few PMID's I got were - 31510805 (dated - 19/9/13), 31536605 (dated - 19/7/20 ). And there are several cases like this for which date is incorrect. Can you guys check that? What is the reason for such discrepancy?

Comment: I used the following code to fetch the information about the paper - 

`handle = Entrez.efetch(db='pubmed', retmode='xml', id=31510805)`

`results = Entrez.read(handle)`


And then used the results to get the date. I just realized there are 2 dates mentioned in the results obtained. One date is the correct one and falls within the supplied filter. The other date is `19/9/13`. (This is for `PMID - 31510805`). Why are there 2 dates, any idea?